# Symfony use Form Event to change data before it submits

Tags: php, symfony

I have the Form Event `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` in place

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;


class AddProfileFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    protected $em;

    function __construct(AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'onPreSubmit'
        );
    }


    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event){

        $interestTags = $event->getData();
        $interestTags = $interestTags['interest'];
        foreach($interestTags as $key => $interestTag){
                $interestTags[$key] = "55";
            }
        }
}
```

Inside the function `onPreSubmit` if i dump the `$event` I can see the following information.

[image]

All I want to do is change the `value` of `key` where you see the red arrow being pointed, so that moving on the rest of the process takes the new `value` rather than the old one.

The approach i used seems to change the value alright but as soon as i move out of the foreach loop the old value remains, what do I need to do so that `qqq` is replaced by for example `444` for rest of the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `onPreSubmit` function, you need to set the events data with the array you modified:

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event){

        $interestTags = $event->getData();
        $interestTags = $interestTags['interest'];
        foreach($interestTags as $key => $interestTag){
                $interestTags[$key] = "55";
            }
        }
        $event->setData($interestTags);
}
```